# MySQL: Get most current value in group by query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables `questions` and `answered`. `answered` contains the answers for all the questions for all the users. One user can answer a question multiple times. A question can be answered correctly or incorrectly.

I am looking for a query that will return the count of correct and incorrect answers over all questions in one category. **I want to use the most current answer only, though.** So if a user answered the same question incorrectly before and correctly more recently, I only want to count the newest - correct - one.

This is what I got so far:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e2e/2/0

```
SELECT a.correct, count(*) as count
FROM answered a JOIN questions q ON a.question_id = q.id 
WHERE a.user_id = 1 AND q.category_id = 1
GROUP BY correct
```

It returns

```
|  CORRECT  |  COUNT  |
-----------------------
|  0        |   2     |
-----------------------
|  1        |   4     |
-----------------------
```

What I want is

```
|  CORRECT  |  COUNT  |
-----------------------
|  0        |   1     |
-----------------------
|  1        |   2     |
-----------------------
```

Comment: How are answers identified as current or earlier? is there a `datetime` column?

Comment: Yes, look at the sqlfiddle.com page he posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query that you need:

```
SELECT a.correct, count(*) as counter
FROM answered a
JOIN (SELECT user_id, question_id, max(created) as maxCreated
      FROM answered
      GROUP BY user_id, question_id) aux
  ON a.user_id = aux.user_id AND
     a.question_id = aux.question_id AND
     a.created = aux.maxCreated
JOIN questions q ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE a.user_id = 1 AND q.category_id = 1
GROUP BY a.correct
```

Use the `aux` sub-query to select only the rows with the last answer to a question from a given user.

Comment: Remove the quotes from `as 'maxCreated'` and `as 'counter'`.

Comment: Single quotes should be used for string literals, not for column names or aliases. That's what double-quotes are for (also backquotes in MySQL).

Comment: A view of current answers rather than a subquery might be a good idea. Depends in part on how the query optimizer treats it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate only correct answers whenever they're given:

```
select b.correct, count(*) from
(
SELECT a.question_id, max(a.correct) correct 
FROM answered a JOIN questions q ON a.question_id = q.id 
WHERE a.user_id = 1 AND q.category_id = 1
GROUP BY a.question_id
 ) B 
group by b.correct
```

If later incorrect answer eliminates correct one and you need only last/current results:

```
select a.correct,count(*) from 
(
select user_id, question_id, max(created) maxDate 
from answered a WHERE a.user_id = 1
group by a.user_id, a.question_id
) m

join answered a 
 on m.question_id=a.question_id 
    and m.user_id=a.user_id
    and m.maxDate=a.created
join questions q on a.question_id=q.id

where q.category_id = 1

group by a.correct
```

Comment: This query gives the intended result but it's incorrect. You are selecting the rows with corrected answers and not the rows with the last answer.

Comment: fixed. I thought only one correct answer needs to mark question answered by user.